# rsyslogd v3.x.x unexpectedly closes write connection to named pipe target

Tags: pipe, syslog, rsyslog, fifo, rsyslogd

I've configured rsyslog to forward certain log messages to a named pipe `/tmp/logger.pipe`. I then have a separate process reading from the named pipe. Relevant section from `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
# Remote Logging (silly conditional rule needed for specific logging scenario)
$template RFC5424Format,"<%PRI%>1 %timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%T%timegenerated:12:19:date-rfc3339%.%timegenerated:21:26:date-rfc3339%Z %HOSTNAME% - - -%msg%\n"
if ($msg contains 'remote="true"') then /tmp/logger.pipe;RFC5424Format
```

Permissions on /tmp/logger.pipe

```
prwxrwxrwx 1 ftp root
```

I'm deploying this application onto two different machines. One machine features rsyslog v3.x.x and the other v5.x.x

[image]

[image]

The application is working wonderfully on the machine with rsyslog v5.x.x. However, I'm experiencing odd behavior on the machine with rsyslog v3.x.x. Specifically:

1. rsyslogd sometimes takes forever to start on initial boot up (it was very snappy prior to me adding the new rule).
2. When the process reading `logger.pipe` restarts, rsyslogd seems to stop writing data to the named pipe after the listening process has resumed. The only way to fix this is to manually issue a restart to rsyslogd

Is there some trick with rsyslog configuration that I'm missing when working with named pipes? Any other permissions issues I may be overlooking? I am confident in the application since it's been working very robustly with the v5.x.x rsyslog version. Unfortunately I have no way to update the v3.x.x version on the machine I'm having issues with.

Any thoughts?

**Update: I may have diagnosed the problem - it appears to be an issue where rsyslogd closes the write connection to the pipe if there are no readers. However, the reader application uses fopen() which blocks until there is a corresponding writer.**

**For some reason this is not an issue on rsyslog v5.x.x:**

1. initial state where rsyslogd and logger.out successfully have pipe open

[image]

2. issue restart on _logger.out, rsyslogd still have write open to pipe

[image]

3. _logger.out resumes and everything functions correctly again

**But this behavior is different on rsyslog v3.x.x:**

1. initial state where rsyslogd and logger.out successfully have pipe open

[image]

2. issue restart on _logger.out, **rsyslogd for some reason closes connection to pipe**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From rsyslog document, it looks like the target should include a pipe symbol. This modification resolved my problem such that rsyslog would maintain an open connection to the named pipe even when the reader closed.

I can't explain why this was only an issue on rsyslog v3.x.x however.

[image]